# Setup MysqlDB Replica for one Schema

Tags: mysql, linux, database-replication

I have mysql8 DB in my Linux server. I want to setup Replica for this DB. In this DB I have multiple schemas, But I want to setup a replica for only one schema.

Is it possible to set up a replica for one schema?

If it is possible what is the process to setup.

Please anyone help regarding this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8,

We can apply below filters:

REPLICATE_DO_DB: Include updates based on database name. Equivalent to --replicate-do-db.

REPLICATE_IGNORE_DB: Exclude updates based on database name. Equivalent to --replicate-ignore-db.

REPLICATE_DO_TABLE: Include updates based on table name. Equivalent to --replicate-do-table.

REPLICATE_IGNORE_TABLE: Exclude updates based on table name. Equivalent to --replicate-ignore-table.

REPLICATE_WILD_DO_TABLE: Include updates based on wildcard pattern matching table name. Equivalent to --replicate-wild-do-table.

REPLICATE_WILD_IGNORE_TABLE: Exclude updates based on wildcard pattern matching table name. Equivalent to --replicate-wild-ignore-table.

REPLICATE_REWRITE_DB: Perform updates on replica after substituting new name on replica for specified database on source. Equivalent to --replicate-rewrite-db.

Example:

> CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER
> REPLICATE_DO_DB = (d1), REPLICATE_IGNORE_DB = (d2);

> CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER
> REPLICATE_WILD_DO_TABLE = ('db1.old%');

> CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER
> REPLICATE_WILD_IGNORE_TABLE = ('db1.new%', 'db2.new%');

> CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER
> REPLICATE_DO_TABLE = ('db1.old');
> CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER REPLICATE_REWRITE_DB = ((db1, db2));

Comment: Thank you @Ajith Daniel. I applied mentioned above it's working.  Please let me know enable multiple schemas to replicate. I have  4 schemas, But i want to replicate 2 schemas  How can it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The version of mysql 8 can be referred to as follows:
change replication FILTER Replicate_Do_TabIe = (testdb) for channel 'testdbchannel';
Mysql 5.7 does not support FILTER.